# Codeigneitor data not inserted to the Database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have create  form and i am trying to store the data using Ajax.but data is not inserted to the database.what can be the error.user_id will be auto increment. and also i want to validate sitename.it should restrict inserting same sitenames.

Here is my code

Controller

```
public function user_add()
    {
                $data_save = array(

                    "Mnumber" => $this->input->post("Mnumber"),
                    "email" => $this->input->post("email"),
                    "fname" => $this->input->post("fname"),
                    "address" => $this->input->post("address"),
                    "sitename" => $this->input->post("sitename"),
                    "title" => $this->input->post("title"),
                    "descr" => $this->input->post("descr")

                );
                if ($this->user_mod->AddUser($data_save)) {
                    echo "Successfully Saved";
                } else {
                    echo "error";
                }

        }
    }
```

Model

```
class user_mod extends CI_Model
{

    public function AddUser($data_save)
    {
        if ($this->db->insert('users', $data_save)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

View

```
<script>
    function save_user_new() {
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        var Mnumber = $('#Mnumber').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var fname = $('#fname').val();
        var address = $('#address').val();
        var sitename = $('#sitename').val();
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var descr = $('#descr').val();


        if (sitename != "" && Mnumber != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                async: false,
                url: "<?php echo site_url('form_con/user_add'); ?>",
                data: { "user_id": user_id,
                    "Mnumber": Mnumber,
                    "email": email,
                    "fname": fname,
                    "address": address,
                    "sitename": sitename,
                    "title": title,
                    "descr": descr,

                },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 'error') {
                        $('#success_msg').hide();
                        $('#error_msg1').show();
                        $('#error_msg1').html("Error : Something wrong.");

                    } else if (data == 'have') {
                        $('#success_msg').hide();
                        $('#error_msg1').show();
                        $('#error_msg1').html("Error : This Employee is already exists.");
                    } else {
                        $('#error_msg1').hide();
                        $('#success_msg').show();
                        $('#success_msg').html("Entitled leave successfully saved.");
                        $('#load_leave').html(data);
                    }

                }

            });
        } else {
            $('#success_msg').hide();
            $('#error_msg1').show();
            $('#error_msg1').html("Error : Please enter Employee Details.");
        }
    }
</script>

<form action="#">

                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Your First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Enter text">
                            <!--<span class="help-block"> A block of help text. </span>-->
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Email Address</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                 </span>

                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Your Mobile Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Mnumber" name="Mnumber" placeholder="Enter text">
                            <!--<span class="help-block"> A block of help text. </span>-->
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Your Address</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter text">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Your Site Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sitename" name="sitename" placeholder="Enter text">
                            <!--<span class="help-block"> A block of help text. </span>-->
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Title of Your Web site</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Enter text">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Description of Your Web Site</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descr" name="descr" placeholder="Enter text">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn green" onclick="save_user_new()">Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: change to development mode from production mode

Comment: @colombo If I am not wrong, you have auto increament user id if that is the case then why you are inserting this from code. Please check the value of userid in code and last user id in database.

Comment: user_id is increment value u should not be inserted this

Comment: Please remove user_id from form and make it auto incremented in database table. After this there is no need to checkUser function

Comment: @Amit Kumar i have done that but still not data insert to the db

Comment: edit the top level index.php and adjust the error_reporting function to use E_ALL" Like This error_reporting(E_ALL); and after this check your error